# Dynamic Height Issue for Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a Custom `UITableViewCell` with a `UICollectionView` in it.

I have the `UICollectionView` pinned to each side in its `XIB` file.

Within some of my cells, the content may carry down but with my current setup for dynamic heights, I am only seeing the top portion. I am adding images to my `UICollectionView` so in one cell there may be 20 while another may just be 5. Right now each row has the same height when some should be different.

To note, the `UICollectionView` in the cell will not scroll.

Here is what I am trying in my View Controller:

```
// Here is where I am getting the arr data, which is the folders
// that contains images.
func getDataForSections() {
    
    let storageReference = Storage.storage()
    let ref = storageReference.reference().child("abc/xyz/")
    
    ref.listAll { (result, error) in
        
        if let error = error {
            // ...
        }
                    
        for prefix in result.prefixes {
            self.arr.append(prefix)
        }
        
        self.myTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    
    return arr.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
    let data = arr[indexPath.section]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as! collectionCell
    cell.getImagesFromData(data: data)
    cell.frame = tableView.bounds
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    cell.collectionView.reloadData()
    cell.collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cell.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height).isActive = true
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    // How Do I get the Custom size here? Or in heightForRowAt?
    return 500.0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

/**
 @param numberOfCellsInCollectionView the number of cells of your current collectioview
 */
func calculateHeight(numberOfCellsInCollectionView: Int) -> CGFloat {
    let imageHeight: CGFloat = 40.0
    let spaceBetweenRows: CGFloat = 20.0 /*Change as you please based on the space you put between your cells (if any) */
    let rows: CGFloat = CGFloat(calculateRows(numberOfCellsInCollectionView: numberOfCellsInCollectionView))
    
    /**
     1) (rows*imageHeight) calculate the total space occupied by the pictures
     2) (rows+2) assuming you want to put a little space between the top and the bottom of the collectionview i used +2. If you don't want to remove the +2
     3) ((rows+2)*spaceBetweenRows) total space occupied by the spaces.
     **/
    let height = (rows*imageHeight)+((rows+2)*spaceBetweenRows)
   
    return height
    
}

//Calculate the rows
func calculateRows(numberOfCellsInCollectionView: Int) -> Int {
    let result = numberOfCellsInCollectionView/6 //Dividing the number of cells for the cells for row
    let rest = numberOfCellsInCollectionView%6 //Calculating the module
    
    if rest == 0 {
        //If the rest is 0 (ie: you divide 18/6), then you get the result of the division (18/6 = 3)
        return result
    } else {
        //If the rest is > 0 (ie: you divide 17/6), then you get the result of the division + 1 (17/6 = 3+1 = 4) so there's space for the last item
        return result+1
    }
}
```

Here is what I am trying in my Custom Cell that has a Collection View:

```
func getImagesFromData(prefix: String) {
    
    let storageReference = Storage.storage()
    let ref = storageReference.reference().child("abc/xyz/\(prefix)")
    
    ref.listAll { (result, error) in
                    
        if let error = error {
            // ...
        }
        
        self.folderImages.removeAll()
                    
        for item in result.items {
            
            if !self.folderImages.contains(item) {
                self.folderImages.append(item)
            }
        }

       // Here is where I need to store (or retain) the count 
       // for each section and then calculate the height or pass
       // this data back to the View Controller. 
       // But with Firebase I am not sure how to return this or 
       // use a completion.
                                            
        // reload collection data
        self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension customCollectionCell: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
        return folderImages.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath) as! imageCell
        let theImage = folderImages[indexPath.item]
        cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: theImage, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "blah")) { (image, error, cacheType, ref) in
            if error != nil {
                cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "blah")
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Another Example:

Here instead of using a `UITableView` with the `UICollectionViewCell`, I made a `UICollectionView` with the `UICollectionViewCell`...

I also use a variation of the method within the cell in the `UIViewController` to get the count.

In this example, I can see the values prior to the return. I just need to know how to get that value within the return as the height.

Here's what I tried:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                  layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                  sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let prefix = arr[indexPath.section]

    getImageCountFromPrefix(prefix: prefix.name, completion: { (count, success) in
        if success {
            self.h = self.calculateHeight(numberOfCellsInCollectionView: count)
            // self.h has a value!!! How do I get it in the return?
        }
    })

    return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.size.width, height: self.h)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to determine the height of the pictures inside the cells then only use the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` function like this :

```swift
 private func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat{
       /* Here I'll just assume the height of the picture is 30. You'll have to put here your function and return the dimension. */
        return 30.0
    }
```

Note that you may want to add a constant value to the returned value to make the cell's appearance more clear. I usually add 70.0

Oh, and I don't know about images, but when you deal with text you have to call these as well in the `cellForRowAt`.

```swift
cell.textLabel?.sizeToFit()
cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
```

Here's how to calculate the height of your collection view

```swift
/**
 @param numberOfCellsInCollectionView the number of cells of your current collectioview
 */
func calculateHeight(numberOfCellsInCollectionView: Int) -> CGFloat{
    let imageHeight: CGFloat = 40.0
    let spaceBetweenRows: CGFloat = 5.0 /*Change as you please based on the space you put between your cells (if any) */
    let rows: CGFloat = CGFloat(calculateRows(numberOfCellsInCollectionView: numberOfCellsInCollectionView))
    
    /**
     1) (rows*imageHeight) calculate the total space occupied by the pictures
     2) (rows+2) assuming you want to put a little space between the top and the bottom of the collectionview i used +2. If you don't want to remove the +2
     3) ((rows+2)*spaceBetweenRows) total space occupied by the spaces.
     **/
    let height = (rows*imageHeight)+((rows+2)*spaceBetweenRows)
   
    return height
    
}

//Calculate the rows
func calculateRows(numberOfCellsInCollectionView: Int) -> Int{
    let result = numberOfCellsInCollectionView/6 //Dividing the number of cells for the cells for row
    let rest = numberOfCellsInCollectionView%6 //Calculating the module
    
    if rest == 0 {
        //If the rest is 0 (ie: you divide 18/6), then you get the result of the division (18/6 = 3)
        return result
    } else {
        //If the rest is > 0 (ie: you divide 17/6), then you get the result of the division + 1 (17/6 = 3+1 = 4) so there's space for the last item
        return result+1
    }
}
```

Comment: Images will be 40x40. The UICollectionView is setup so there will be 6 in a row.

Comment: Right, my bad, I ignored part of the question. However you should calculate the height of the collection view and return it in the heightForRowAtIndexPath. You should also call cell.sizeToFit() but I don't know the equivalent of numberOfLines. Let me know If you need more help

Comment: Any recommendations on the best approach to calculating the UICollectionView height? So right now I am getting values that look to be what I need, but it's after everything else has loaded. So not sure how to get that value returned properly.

Comment: I appreciate your assistance with this. So, while these do return values that look to be what I need, I'm still stumped on where I should call these. All of my setup is loaded before I can get the value(s) to pass into this. I'm using Firebase. so I'm wondering if it's due to that. I can't seem to find how I can return values from their methods in a way I can use them in any sizing methods.

Comment: Call calculate height in heightForRowAtIndexPath to make it the return value.  It's not a problem if you can't access the data before you load the view. You can create helper variables which you'll assign values after you'll load the data you need. Use those helper variables instead the data you're missing.

Comment: I have updated my code to see if that may help in any way. I'm using Firebase. So in the View Controller I'm getting the data needed about the folders & then passing in the folder value to the custom cell to get the images & set up the collection view. I need to get that count back to the View Controller on each cell & refresh that view to update the height (I believe). That's where I am currently stuck.

Comment: I added a new example that is using a UICollectionView vs. UITableView & using sizeForItemAt. In that scenario, using your suggestions above, I can see the height value, I just don't know how to use that value as the height.